# Why does numpy.where() give two arrays with an array of more than 1 row as input?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I understand the output of `np.where()` with input of a one-row array. However, when a two-row array was used as an input, I don't understand why the output of b is two arrays.

The output for a[b] makes sense.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]])
print(a)
print ('Indices of elements <4')
b = np.where(a<4)
print(b) 
print(a[b])
```

output for b:

```
(array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

output for a[b]:

```
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: What do you think the output should have been, instead? Why? Anyway, Stack Overflow is not the right place to get a justification for a library's design decisions.

Comment: Because I am used to R, I truly don't understand the output from numpy. Everyone starts from being a beginner right? I am confused because you always posted some discouraging words after I asked a question. I am a statistician trying to learn something new, since I was not educated in a big data era and am trying to catch up.

Comment: With multidimensional indexing the use of a tuple is significantly different from a list.  It provides one value for each dimension.  `a[(i,j)]` is not the same as `a[np.array([i,j])]`.  `b` is a tuple of arrays, and thus can be used directly in the `a[b]` expression.  Compare that with `np.argwhere(a<4)` which returns the same numbers but as a (3,2) array.

Comment: I see. thanks! good to know. I tried with 3 rows. The pattern is clear. First array in b corresponds to row number, second array in b corresponds to column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require two indices to access each element in 2D array. For eg. i and j.
Hence, if the indices of the 2D array satisfying the condition are `(i1,j1), (i2,j2) and (i3,j3)` for condition `a<4`, then `np.where()` will return a tuple of tuples in format like `((i1,i2,i3),(j1,j2,j3))`

Comment: I see. thanks. I was expecting an array of two rows. therefore was confused. It makes sense now. The first output array seems to indicate which row the indices refer to.

Comment: @hehe If the answer helped you, please consider validating the answer as correct!